# CSS Transform Origin Repositions Oddly When Window Size is Adjusted in Safari?

Tags: css, safari, css-animations, css-transforms

Though it appears to work fine in Firefox, I can't seem to figure out why the background image class below, (`.sitebg`), repositions erratically when the browser window size is adjusted in the Safari web browser. The `transform-origin` jumps oddly when the window is adjusted, but I have yet to know what's causing that to happen...

Is this some kind of bug, or do I need to implement something for better cross-browser compatibility?

See the snippet below for further reference.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
  background: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}


/* -- Site Background -- */

.sitebg {
  background: url(http://maxpixel.freegreatpicture.com/static/photo/1x/Seamless-Repeating-Tiling-Tile-able-Tileable-1889447.jpg);
  background-size: 720px 720px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 1000%;
  height: 1000%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

@-moz-keyframes bg-rotate {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bg-rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  }
}

@keyframes bg-rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform-origin: top left;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform-origin: top left;
  }
}


/* -- Stack Ordering -- */

.sitebg {
  z-index: -1;
}

body {
  z-index: -2;
}


/* -- Media Queries -- */

@media only screen and (min-width:2000px) {
  .sitebg {
    -webkit-animation: 800s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: 800s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -o-animation: 800s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: 800s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    animation: 800s bg-rotate infinite linear;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 2000px) and (min-width: 1500px) {
  .sitebg {
    -webkit-animation: 700s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: 700s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -o-animation: 700s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: 700s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    animation: 700s bg-rotate infinite linear;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .sitebg {
    -webkit-animation: 600s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: 600s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -o-animation: 600s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: 600s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    animation: 600s bg-rotate infinite linear;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 600px) {
  .sitebg {
    -webkit-animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -o-animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .sitebg {
    -webkit-animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -o-animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sitebg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like using percentage values for the `width` and `height` were causing the glitch to occur. Though I am not sure if this is the best solution to date, this worked for me:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
  background: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}


/* -- Site Background -- */

.sitebg {
  background: url(http://maxpixel.freegreatpicture.com/static/photo/1x/Seamless-Repeating-Tiling-Tile-able-Tileable-1889447.jpg);
  background-size: 720px 720px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 6788px;
  height: 6788px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

@-moz-keyframes bg-rotate {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bg-rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  }
}

@keyframes bg-rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform-origin: top left;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform-origin: top left;
  }
}


/* -- Stack Ordering -- */

.sitebg {
  z-index: -1;
}

body {
  z-index: -2;
}


/* -- Media Queries -- */

@media only screen and (min-width:2000px) {
  .sitebg {
    -webkit-animation: 800s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: 800s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -o-animation: 800s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: 800s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    animation: 800s bg-rotate infinite linear;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 2000px) and (min-width: 1500px) {
  .sitebg {
    -webkit-animation: 700s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: 700s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -o-animation: 700s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: 700s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    animation: 700s bg-rotate infinite linear;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .sitebg {
    -webkit-animation: 600s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: 600s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -o-animation: 600s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: 600s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    animation: 600s bg-rotate infinite linear;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 600px) {
  .sitebg {
    -webkit-animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -o-animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .sitebg {
    -webkit-animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -o-animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
    animation: 500s bg-rotate infinite linear;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sitebg"></div>
```